# IOS development, return function with if and else and autorelease

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I'm in my first big app and I'm having a bit of a problem with memory management here.

```
-(id) dateFormatter:(id)date{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    if([date isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        return [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
     else
        return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Now, As I see it, every return in this example need a autorelease at the end. But when I add the autorelease i am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and without it every thing is working great. I analyzed the problem and got that there are too many autorelease in the function, but i can't see how can i release the memory of the NSDateFormatter without it.

Can any one explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about doing:

```
-(id) dateFormatter:(id)date{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

    id retVal;
    if([date isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        retVal = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
     else
        retVal = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return retVal;

}
```

Comment: Sure I can do that, But isn't a way to it the way i tried? Thank you, This is the obvious way and if this is the way to do it, then that is what i will do :-)

Comment: It looks as if you were adding the `autorelease` to the wrong object. From your question, I gather you were doing: `[[dateFormatter dateFromString:date] autorelease];` You should have been putting it on: `[[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];`

Answer (score 2):

Why not using autorelease?

```
-(id) dateFormatter:(id)date{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    if([date isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        return [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
     else
        return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could alternatively do this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Its also possible that you are not correctly assigning the returned variable when it comes back.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, couple of problems. First is, you are using dateFormatter but you are not returning it. So, when you initialise dateFormatter you need to either call autorelease on it, or you have to have NSDateFormatter give you an autoreleased object.

For example:

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

or

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatter];

the second method doesn't exist but it's good to know how these things normally work. Anyway, going with the first method above will fix your code.

When you call [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] or [dateFormatter dateFromString:date], dateFormatter will give you back a NSString or an NSDate respectively. In both cases, the respective method, stringFromDate:date or dateFromString:date creates for you an autoreleased NSString or NSDate object.

You can then return either object as-is because it's already autoreleased.